# Шифрование Blowfish.

Tags: blowfish, криптография, шифрование

Добрый день, друзья!

Натолкнулся на еще одну интересную работу - разработка шифрования методом Blowfish. Раньше о таком шифровании не слышал даже, честно говоря, потому прошу помощи у тех, кто с этим работал.
Есть где алгоритм на каком-либо языке программирования? Неважно, будет ли это Delph, C#, js или php, главное - понять суть, потому что, глядя на эту картинку, не совсем понятно, что и как организовать алгоритм этот.

[image]

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/140394/

Comment: @iksuy, есть алгоритм Сеть Фейстеля на php или хотя бы Delphi, C#? Java и c++ знаю очень плохо, потому боюсь не разберу код на нем, а лучше весь пример шифрования Blowfish.

Comment: @IntegralAL, вам это зачем? Хотите сами реализовать Blowfish или вам нужно что-то зашифровать в прикладных целях?

Comment: @Barmaley, просто дали задание нашифровать данные в базу через Blowfish, язык программирования желательно php. Хотя можно на Delphi, C#, JavaScript также увидеть код, собственно на чем я пишу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужно чисто утилитарно зашифровать некие данные, то проще взять готовую библиотеку и забыть о том, как происходит шифрование. В противном случае вы рискуете увязнуть в массе тонкостей и в итоге получить [змеиное масло aka Snake Oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_oil_(cryptography)).

Уверяю вас, это непросто, криптография это целая наука, в которой все компоненты должны быть точно уравновешены, дозированы и выверены:

1. Сам способ шифрования
2. Метод хэширования.
3. Алгоритм генерации ключей.
4. Алгоритм соления.
5. Выбор ГСЧ.
6. Алгоритм сцепления блоков.
7. И т.д.

Если хотя бы одна из указанных компонент вам неизвестна, то вам надо или посвятить несколько месяцев жизни на изучение криптографии или заняться поиском либы для шифрования. Если речь идет о PHP, то [начните отсюда](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php), если речь идет C#, то рекомендую погуглить Bouncy Castle.

**Update**

Приведенная выше функция `crypt()` - это не совсем шифровщик, а алгоритм хэширования где может применяться Blowfish. Примеры на PHP можно надыбать например [здесь](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous-Code/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-using-Blowfish/) или [здесь](http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_Blowfish/docs/latest/li_Crypt_Blowfish.html)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, только один вопрос, ссылка, что на php, там же просто получение hash идет через crypt, это мало общего имеет с тем, что мне надо добиться создания шифрования Blowfish?

Comment: @IntegralAL см. апдейт ответа